# Can I drink Weight Gainer after Workout and Whey before bed?

Tags: time-of-day, whey-protein, body-building, body-shape

I have this questions in my head and couldn't find the answers in google.

So i am 171 cm with a weight of 68. Its Actually quite ideal. But I wanted to grow bigger. I've been using Nitrotech Whey Isolate (Protein) for about 6 months already, and have seen some good changes.

Since I am curious with Weight Gainers, I just bought one Masstech. I wanted to know if it is actually alright to consume Mass gainer after workout and then Whey protein before bed.

Because if i have to consume mass gainer before bed, I'm scared that i will grow up to be fat.

Thank you, your feedback means a lot to me.

Cheers.